# How to convert python datetime to timestamp and insert in oracle database using to_sql

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, timestamp, pandas-to-sql

I get `DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "DAT_ULT_ALT": invalid identifier` when I try to  insert a datetime to a timestamp in oracle using to_sql from pandas with SQL Alchemy engine. My code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

import datetime

import itertools

...

oracle_db = sa.create_engine('oracle://username:password@host:port/database')

connection= oracle_db.connect()

...

dat_ult_alt = datetime.datetime.now()

df_plano['DAT_ULT_ALT'] = pd.Series(list(itertools.repeat(dat_ult_alt, max)))
df_plano.to_sql('table_name', connection, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

This code works to fields of type "Date" but does not work with fields of type "timestamp". Do you know what I need to do to convert dat_ult_alt to timestamp?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Oracle Data Types](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/oracle.html#oracle-data-types) of the sqlalchemy documentation. In the module `sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle` you can find the datatype `TIMESTAMP`. Import it and set it as dtype for the relevant column like this.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle import TIMESTAMP
df_plano.to_sql('table_name', connection, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={'DAT_ULT_ALT':TIMESTAMP})
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about *sqlalchemy* as I have never used it with Oracle. Here's a sample code  using **Cx_Oracle**  which works.

```
create table test ( tstamp TIMESTAMP);
```

---

```
import cx_Oracle
import datetime
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('usr/pwd@//host:1521/db')
cur = conn.cursor()
dtime=datetime.datetime.now()
cur.prepare( "INSERT INTO test(tstamp) VALUES(:ts)" )
cur.setinputsizes(ts=cx_Oracle.TIMESTAMP)
cur.execute(None, {'ts':dtime})
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

---

```
select * from test;

TSTAMP                        
------------------------------
22-11-18 09:14:19.422278000 PM
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I need a solution with sqlalchemy  instead of cx_oracle so that I can insert the role dataframe with 3 millions rows to the oracle table at once, with one command to_sql(), so I cannot treat